# Bash: ignore special character

Tags: bash, cat, tr

I have this code

```
 cat SomeFile | tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '\n' |tr -d 0-9 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' > net.txt
```

I want to read a file and ignore those characters.The output would be one word per line except if its a website.

```
 \'#$%.,:;?!&*|()[]"<>=-
```

how i can do this by using only cat and tr ?

the output should look like this

```
other
branches
examples
for
developers
http//drupalorg/project/examples
what
is
this
this
set
of
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an input `SomeFile`:

> Examples:for9 developers>http://example.org/examples?s=%20&<what>
>   is, this?

produce an output of:

```
examples
for
developers
http://example.org/examples?s=%20&
what
is
this
```

---

I suppose this *could* be done using only `tr`+shell:

```
for i in $(<SomeFile tr -cs ']a-zA-Z0-9/:.%?=&_,+()~['\''#$;!*-' '\n' | \
    tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'); do
    case "$i" in
        *://*)
            echo "$i" >> net.txt ;;
        *)
            for split in $(echo "$i" | tr -c 'a-z' '\n'); do
                echo "$split" >> net.txt
            done ;;
    esac
done
```

---

But it may be simpler to add `grep` to `tr`:

```
< SomeFile tr -cs ']a-zA-Z0-9/:.%?=&_,+()~['\''#$;!*-' '\n' | \
    tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | grep -o '.*://.*\|[a-z]*' > net.txt
```

- There's no need for `cat` either – just direct the file into the standard input for `tr`

---

grep:

```
grep -oE '[a-zA-Z]+://[]a-zA-Z0-9/:.%?=&_,+()~['\''#$;!*-]+|[[:alpha:]]+' \
    -- SomeFile | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' > net.txt
```

---

With `zsh` an array could be used:

```
file=( ${(L)=$(< SomeFile)//[^]a-zA-Z0-9\/:.%?=&_,+()~[\'#$;!*-]/ } )
printf '%s\n' ${(M)file:#*://*} ${=${file:#*://*}//[^a-z]/ }
```

- This prints all urls first, followed by any "words"

Answer (score 2):

You can use a couple of translations:

```
tr "'"'\#$%.,:;?!&*|()[]"<>=-' ' ' <SomeFile | tr -s '[:space:]' "\n"
```

The first operation converts any of the characters you don't want into a space. The second operation converts all whitspace (including newlines) into a newline, squeezing runs of newlines to a single character.